# ffmpeg batch script for video resizing

Tags: bash

I have a few hundred mp4 files (thanks android =/) that I need to convert. I only want to convert videos that are too large (>= 1080p) and I do want to keep the exif Information so the timeline is not broken.

I hope someone can look over the script to point me to some grave mistakes or give some improvement.

Anything I am missing? Thanks in advance.

```
resize() {
    echo "Filename $1"
    filename=$(basename -- "$1")
    extension="${filename##*.}"
    filename="${filename%.*}"
    new_filename=${filename}.${timestamp}.${extension}
    ffmpeg -v quiet -stats -i $1 -map_metadata 0 \ 
    -vf scale=-1:720 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 \
    -c:a copy $new_filename < /dev/null
    exiftool -TagsFromFile $1 "-all:all>all:all" -overwrite_original     $new_filename
}

if [[ -d $1 ]]; then
    timestamp=$(date +%s)
    echo "Finding Video Files ..."
    exiftool $1/*.mp4 -if '$ImageHeight >= 1080' -p '$Filename' > /tmp/fl_$timestamp

    echo "Processing Video Files ..."
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        resize $line
    done < /tmp/fl_$timestamp
    rm /tmp/fl_$timestamp
elif [[ -f $1 ]]; then
    resize $1
else
    echo "Argument missing"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Consider portable shell

The only Bash feature we're using is `[[ ]]`  for testing file properties.  It's easy to replace `[[ -d $1 ]]` with `[ -d "$1" ]` and that allows us to stick with standard shell, which is more portable and lower overhead:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

## Careful with quoting

Most of shellcheck's output is due to failure to quote parameter expansions:

```
236052.sh:9:31: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
236052.sh:9:50: error: Delete trailing spaces after \ to break line (or use quotes for literal space). [SC1101]
236052.sh:10:5: warning: This flag is used as a command name. Bad line break or missing [ .. ]? [SC2215]
236052.sh:11:15: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
236052.sh:12:28: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
236052.sh:12:74: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
236052.sh:18:14: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
236052.sh:18:27: note: Expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that. [SC2016]
236052.sh:18:53: note: Expressions don't expand in single quotes, use double quotes for that. [SC2016]
236052.sh:18:75: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
236052.sh:22:16: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
236052.sh:23:20: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
236052.sh:24:16: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
236052.sh:26:12: note: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting. [SC2086]
```

Ironically, you do have quotes in some places they aren't strictly necessary, so it's unclear why you missed all these.

## Errors go to standard output

> ```
> echo "Argument missing"
> exit 1
> ```

That should be:

> ```
> echo >&2 "Argument missing"
> exit 1
> ```

The test here is slightly wrong: the argument may be present, but not the name of a plain file or directory.  So I'd replace that with:

```
elif [ -e "$1" ]
    echo "$1: not a plain file or directory" >&2
    exit 1
elif [ "$1" ]
    echo "$1: file not found" >&2
    exit 1
else
    echo "Argument missing" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

It may be worthwhile to move that testing into the `resize` function, because at present we assume that the contents found in directory arguments are plain files (that said, we're covering a tiny corner case with that, so I wouldn't sweat it - just let the commands there fail).

## Don't assume previous commands succeeded

In `resize`, if `ffmpeg` fails, there's little point running `exiftool`, so connect them with `&&`.  Also consider removing the file if it was created with errors (so we're not fooled by a partly-written output into thinking this file doesn't need conversion).

## Avoid temporary files

There's no need for the file `/tmp/fl_$timestamp`: we could simply use a pipeline there.

## Consider accepting more arguments

Instead of only allowing a single argument (and ignoring all but the first), let the user specify as many files as needed; it's easy to loop over them using `for`.

## Handle directories using recursion

Instead of the `while` loop, we could invoke our script recursively using `xargs`.  I'll make it a separate function for clarity:

```
resize_dir() {
    exiftool "$1"/*.mp4 -if '$ImageHeight >= 1080' -p '$Filename' |
        xargs -r -d '\n' -- "$0" || status=false
}
```

(`xargs -r` is a GNU extension to avoid running the command with no arguments.  If this option isn't available, we'll need to modify the script so that passing no arguments isn't an error.)

---

## Modified code

This is Shellcheck-clean, but I'm not able to test it (lacking the requisite directory of MPEG files).

```
#!/bin/sh

set -eu


status=true
fail() {
    echo "$@" >&2
    status=false
}

# Resize a single file
resize() {
    echo "Filename $1"
    filename=$(basename -- "$1")
    extension=${filename##*.}
    filename=${filename%.*}
    new_filename=${filename}.${timestamp}.${extension}
    if 
        ffmpeg -v quiet -stats -i "$1" -map_metadata 0 \
               -vf scale=-1:720 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 \
               -c:a copy "$new_filename" < /dev/null &&
            exiftool -TagsFromFile "$1" '-all:all>all:all' \
                     -overwrite_original "$new_filename"
    then
        # success
        true
    else
        # failed; destroy the evidence
        rm -f "$new_filename" 2>/dev/null
        fail "Failed to convert $1"
    fi
}

# Resize all *.mp4 files in a single directory
# N.B. only immediate contents; not recursive
resize_dir() {
    # shellcheck disable=SC2016
    exiftool "$1"/*.mp4 -if '$ImageHeight >= 1080' -p '$Filename' |
        xargs -r -d '\n' -- "$0" || status=false
}

[ $# -gt 0 ] || fail "Usage: $0 FILE FILE..."

timestamp=$(date +%s)

for arg
do
    if [ -d "$arg" ]
    then
        resize_dir "$arg"
    elif [ -f "$arg" ]
    then
        resize "$arg"
    elif [ -e "$arg" ]
    then
        fail "$arg: not a plain file or directory"
    else
        fail "$arg: file not found"
    fi
done

exec $status # true or false
```

Comment: Aren't `[[` a feature worth using more current shells for?

Comment: @chicks, that's very much a value judgement.  For me, being able to omit quoting from those file tests isn't a feature worth sacrificing portability for.  If we were using `[[` for regular expression matching (which doesn't have such a simple standard equivalent), then the trade-off might go the other way.

Comment: It doesn't have anything do with regular expressions.  It has to do with making shell programming less confusing for folks coming from other languages.  https://www.tothenew.com/blog/foolproof-your-bash-script-some-best-practices/ explains this in point 6.  I'd consider `[[` a best practice that is worth moving to ksh or bash for.

Comment: That's a strange perspective - to me, it *adds* confusion because there's suddenly a context where quoting works differently.