# ffmpeg batch script for video resizing - improved

Tags: bash

I posted a question here [ffmpeg batch script for video resizing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/236052/ffmpeg-batch-script-for-video-resizing) but I forgot the issue of the rotation and the video files were scaled with wrong dimensions.

Below is the improved version of the script

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu


status=true
fail() {
    echo "$@" >&2
    status=false
}

# Resize a single file
resize() {
    exiftool -p 'Filename:$filename Megapixel:$megapixels Dimension:$imagesize Rotation:$rotation' $1
    if exiftool -if '$imageheight == 1920 && $imageheight == 1080' $1 >     /dev/null
    then
        fail "-> No need to convert"
        return
    fi

    filename="$(date +%s)".mp4
    rotation=$(exiftool -p '$rotation' $1) 

    if [ "${rotation}" -eq 0 ] || [ "${rotation}" -eq 180 ]
    then
        scaling="-1:720"
    elif [ "${rotation}" -eq 90 ] || [ "${rotation}" -eq 270 ]
    then
        scaling="720:-1"
    else
        fail "-> Unhandled rotation"
        return
    fi

    if 
        ffmpeg -v error -stats -i "$1" -map_metadata 0 \
               -vf scale="$scaling" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 \
               -c:a copy "$filename" < /dev/null &&
            exiftool -TagsFromFile "$1" '-all:all>all:all' \
                     -overwrite_original "$filename"
    then
        # success
        rename 's/.mp4/.success.mp4/' $1 
        mv "$filename" $1
        true
    else
        rename 's/.mp4/.error.mp4/' $1 
        # failed; destroy the evidence
        rm -f "$filename" 2>/dev/null
        fail "-> Failed to convert"
    fi
}

[ $# -gt 0 ] || fail "Usage: $0 FILE FILE..."

for arg
do
    if [ -f "$arg" ]
    then
        resize "$arg"
        echo
    elif [ -e "$arg" ]
    then
        fail "$arg: not a plain file or directory"
    else
        fail "$arg: file not found"
    fi
done

exec $status # true or false
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it intended that `date` is executed separately for each input, or should all converted files have consistent names (for that use of the script)?  It's certainly worth a comment explaining your choice.

I'm not a fan of the big space in the redirection `>     /dev/null` - that makes it harder to parse.

This `if`/`else` chain looks a little clumsy:

> ```
> if [ "${rotation}" -eq 0 ] || [ "${rotation}" -eq 180 ]
> then
>     scaling="-1:720"
> elif [ "${rotation}" -eq 90 ] || [ "${rotation}" -eq 270 ]
> then
>     scaling="720:-1"
> else
>     fail "-> Unhandled rotation"
>     return
> fi
> ```

When testing a single value against various possibilities, it tends to be neater using `case`:

```
case "$rotation" in
    0|180) scaling="-1:720" ;;
    90|270) scaling="720:-1" ;;
    *) fail "-> Unhandled rotation '$rotation'"; return ;;
esac
```

(I also added extra information in the failure case, that may help diagnose problem input files).